# How does Gust of Wind interact with Stinking Cloud?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e

My character is standing near a [Stinking Cloud](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/stinkingCloud.htm). He has the ability to cast [Gust of Wind](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/gustOfWind.htm).

What happens if he casts Gust of Wind in the direction of the stinking cloud? Does the cloud disperse completely? Does a line down the middle clear away? Something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Gust of Wind disperses Stinking Cloud.

[Stinking Cloud](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/stinkingCloud.htm) inherits its rules for wind interaction from the [Fog Cloud](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/fogCloud.htm) spell, which says:

> A moderate wind (11+ mph) disperses the fog in 4 rounds; a strong wind (21+ mph) disperses the fog in 1 round.

The [Gust of Wind](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/gustOfWind.htm) spell says:

> This spell creates a severe blast of air (approximately 50 mph) that originates from you...

This is more than severe enough to meet the criteria for dispersing a Fog Cloud spell (and therefore also a Stinking Cloud spell) in a single round (which is also the duration of Gust of Wind).  Furthermore, the spell description specifies:

> In addition to the effects noted, a gust of wind can do anything that a sudden blast of wind would be expected to do.

Note that if the Stinking Cloud has been made permanent via the [Permanency](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/permanency.htm) spell, it will be reform after 10 minutes, rather than being permanently dispersed, per the spell description:

> A permanent stinking cloud dispersed by wind reforms in 10 minutes.

Comment: I know you're correct, but I think that the answer should also address the fact that the *gust of wind* spell description says that the magic gust "can… blow gases or vapors to the edge of its range." (Do any gas or vapor effects say specifically that they're shoved rather than dispersed?)

Comment: That excerpt might mean "gases and vapors to the edge of the range of this spell are blown away" rather than "gases and vapors in the range of this spell are shoved to the end of the range of this spell".